# what is the purpose of this mysql query?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(lastname,', ',firstname) AS fullname, lastname, firstname
                   FROM " . TABLE_CONTACT . "
                   WHERE  
                     CONCAT(firstname,' ', lastname) LIKE '%$goTo%' OR
                     CONCAT(firstname,' ', middlename,' ', lastname) LIKE '%$goTo%' OR
                     nickname LIKE '%$goTo%' 
                     ORDER BY fullname";
```

Can anyone please tell me what is purpose of above query ? I am new to mysql so unable to understand it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will query the DB and get the `id` and create a full name `CONCAT(lastname,', ',firstname)` from both first and last name fields and also return them separately `lastname, firstname`
FROM the contacts table `TABLE_CONTACT`
WHERE the variable passed `%$goTo%` should match:

Imagine this record in the DB:

```
id      firstname       lastname        middlaname      nickname
5454    Ibrahim         Faour           Ali             ifaour
```

1- `CONCAT(firstname,' ', lastname)` = `Ibrahim Faour`
2- OR `CONCAT(firstname,' ', middlename,' ', lastname)` = `Ibrahim Ali Faour`
3- `nickname` = `ifaour`

And them order them by the newly created column `fullname`

Answer (score 5):

it will search for contacts, by nickname, or fullname, or fullname with initial. Also, it will return them in alphabetical order.

Comment: CONCAT(lastname,', ',firstname) means joining last and firstname ?